# Colunas vazias de uma planilha quando uso o read() do pandas

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

```
import pandas as pd

wb = pd.ExcelFile("meus_dados.xlsx")

sheet_1 = pd.read_excel("meus_dados.xlsx", sheet_name=0)

print sheet_1
```

essa linha de código me traz essa resposta:

```
             Nome          CPF     ...      Unnamed: 8  Unnamed: 9
0     Silvio José  10575674451     ...             NaN         NaN
1  Carlos Alberto  10767764330     ...             NaN         NaN
2  Maria Madalena  23323234343     ...             NaN         NaN
3    Caio Bezerra  10992329221     ...             NaN            
4  Mateus Alencar  10732393213     ...             NaN         NaN

[5 rows x 10 columns]
```

Não sei o porquê de aparecer essas colunas vazias em 8 e 9. Quando leio outra planilha não aparece colunas vazias.

Comment: E qual é a planilha?

Comment: Independente disso, você não deveria estar trabalhando com Python 2 -a versão 2.7 foi lançada há 10 anos atrás (as micro-versões são apenas correções de segurança) - e todo o o suporte vai ser descontinuado a partir de 1 de janeiro de 2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

￼￼Sobre a planilha - ela lógicamente contém algum dado nessas colunas - podem ser simples caracteres de espaço em branco em alguma célula (a coluna 9, na linha 3 parece ser um indiciativo de um desses). Simplesmente selecione as colunas 8 e 9 no excel e remova seu conteúdo, então salve o arquivo de novo.

Se você tiver isso acontecendo em muitas planilhas e preferir automatizar esse filtro, aí vale a pena passar um "apply" e remover colunas que só tenham valores "NaN" ou strings com white-space. Mas para uma única planilha, o melhor é limpar o original.

Comment: Apagar os dados das células não funcionou, mas criei uma nova planilha e deu certo. Muito obrigado!